# Jquery UI datepicker onselect swallowing change event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

[check out this fiddle with opened console](http://jsbin.com/evudo/1448/)

JS

```
   jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#test1').datepicker();

   jQuery('#test2').datepicker({
      onSelect: function ()
                {
                   this.focus();

                }
   });


  jQuery("input").bind("change", function(){
    console.error("change detected");
  });


  });
```

HTML

```
 <input type="text" id="test1"></input>
 <input type="text" id="test2"></input>
```

test2 will not trigger the change event. Is there a clean solution to this, without me having to check myself if the value has changed?

What I basically want to do onselect is focus the datepicker again. At the moment the implementation just blurs focus, and the user cannot tab to the next field.

**EDIT** This is only the explanation why I need `onSelect`. I still need the onchange event to do other stuff (check user input, send ajax request)

Comment: `input` elements do not need to be closed; so please remove `</input>`.

Comment: Couldn't you just make the datepicker for test2 use `onSelect: function () {$(this).focus()}`?

Comment: @j08691 I still need the onchange event to trigger

Comment: You can use the `onSelect` as `onchange`. If you need something to happen in the `onchange` just put it in `onSelect`. You can identify the individual input by `id` in the `onSelect` to customize any code that you want to fire in `onchange`

Comment: @jk. well, I want the onchange to happen, when a change occurs. When you select the same date twice, no change should occur theoretically.

Comment: could someone help me and tell me how to try to improve this question?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have to trigger the change event manually.

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#test1').datepicker();

   jQuery('#test2').datepicker({
      onSelect: function ()
                {
                  //Do all your stuffs here
                  //Then add this line to trigger the change event manually.
                  $(this).change();
                }
   });


  jQuery("input").bind("change", function(){
    console.error("change detected");
  });


  });
```

### **Demo**

Answer (score 0):

You can class the inputs to make adding the `datepicker` a easier but note that it can be done any number of ways. Here's an example with a class:

```
<input type="text" id="test1" class="datepicker" />
<input type="text" id="test2" class="datepicker" />
```

And the jquery:

```
jQuery(function() {

    jQuery(".datepicker").datepicker({
      onSelect: function (selectedDate, ele)
            {
              console.error(selectedDate);
              console.error(ele.id);
              this.focus();
            }
   });

});
```

[jsbin fiddle](http://jsbin.com/xicisaba/1)